# Using Aeron with RSocket

Tags: java, rsocket, aeron

Good morning,

I am trying to use RSocket on top of the Aeron transport protocol. However, it appears that there is no documentation on the topic - did anyone successfully integrate those two technologies together ?
Is it ready to be used or still a work in progress ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the github not helpful? https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-transport-aeron

Comment: The aeron transport for RSocket does work, but it is still a WIP. We have not yet created any documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with R-socket authors about Aeron's support. They say it's very deep in work in progress.
Currently, they have a big issue with converting R-socket byte buffers (they reuse Netty bb) to UnsafeByteBuffer from Agrona. So they have to copy from one to another just because there is no obvious copy-free converter.

So, answering your question:

> Is it ready to be used or still a work in progress?

It's not ready to be used right now unfortunately =(